# Splitting an array into 2D or two arrays

Tags: c#

I have a text file that I am reading to pull out register values and what they contain.

2 lines from the array pulled out is: (full list is about 700)

`0x0003 = 0x0069`

`0x0007 = 0x0078`

I would like to split these into two arrays or one 2-dimensional array, whatever is best(I am new to using arrays)

My goal is to search the array for example for register 3, find the index then extract the information from the 2nd arrays corresponding index.

Here is my code so far ,

```
  List<string> registerFullList1 = new List<string>();

     for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) 
       {
          string[] importStringArray1 = new string[2000];
          importStringArray1[i] = importStringArray1[i] + objReader.ReadLine() + "\r\n";
          //code to extract register info from string array
          string listsplit1 = Regex.Match(importStringArray1[i], @"(?<= 0x)[0-9A-Fa-z\s\=]{13}").Value; 


          if (listsplit1.Contains("0x")) //code to add to list only registers and ignore empty lines
            {
              registerFullList1.Add(Convert.ToString(listsplit1));
            }

                }

  int[] index = new int[2000]; // is there a way here that I don't have to assign  0,1,2,3 to each assignment?

  index[0] = registerFullList1.FindIndex(x => x.StartsWith("0003 ="));
  Register3.Text = Regex.Match(registerFullList1[index[0]], @"(?<= 0x)[0-9A-F]{4}").Value; 

  index[1] = registerFullList1.FindIndex(x => x.StartsWith("0007 ="));
  Register7.Text = Regex.Match(registerFullList1[index[1]], @"(?<= 0x)[0-9A-F]{4}").Value;
```

This all works no problem and I am displaying the register content in text boxes. But I would like two arrays so it is more proper, one with register numbers and one with content. I cant figure it out, any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

final code after reading answers,

```
    List<string> registerNumberList = new List<string>();
    List<string> registerContentList = new List<string>();                 
    List<string> registerFullList = new List<string>();

     for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
       {
         string[] importStringArray1 = new string[2000];
         importStringArray1[i] = importStringArray1[i] + objReader.ReadLine() + "\r\n";

         string listsplit1 = Regex.Match(importStringArray1[i], @"(?<= 0x)[0-9A-Fa-z\s\=]{13}").Value; // @"(?<== 0x)[0-9A-F]{4}"  
         string listsplit2 = Regex.Match(importStringArray1[i], @"(?<= 0x)[0-9A-Fa-z\s\=]{4}").Value;// pulls out the register number from original array
           string listsplit3= Regex.Match(importStringArray1[i], @"(?<== 0x)[0-9A-Fa-z\s\=]{4}").Value;//pulls out register content from original array

         if (listsplit1.Contains("0x"))
           {
              registerNumberList.Add(Convert.ToString(listsplit3));//makes a list with register numbers
              registerContentList.Add(Convert.ToString(listsplit2) );//makes a list with register content
              registerFullList.Add(Convert.ToString(listsplit2) + "=" + Convert.ToString(listsplit3));//the full list

                    }

                }

                Dictionary <string, string> registers = registerFullList.Select(line => line.Split('=')
                         .ToArray())
                         .ToDictionary(items => items[0], items => items[1]);   //joins the register numbers and content into a dictionary with just 4 decimal values for each

                 list1.Text = String.Join("\r\n", registerFullList);



                list2.Text =  registers["0010"]; // pulls out register info
```

Thanks guys

Comment: Use `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest using *Linq*:

If you insist on the array:

```
  int[][] result = File
    .ReadLines(@"C:\myFile.txt")
    .Select(line => line
       .Split('=')
       .Select(item => Convert.ToInt32(item, 16))
       .ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```

In case first index is *unique* one (and thus can serve as a *key*) you can materialize the data as a *dictionary*:

```
  Dictionary<int, int> result = File
    .ReadLines(@"C:\myFile.txt")
    .Select(line => line
       .Split('=')
       .Select(item => Convert.ToInt32(item, 16))
       .ToArray())
    .ToDictionary(items => items[0], items => items[1]);

  ...

  // value == 0x0078 (120)
  int value = result[0x0007];
```

Comment: The first array is unique, I will research Dictionary now and try out your code

Answer (score 0):

Try using a dictionary :

```
Dictionary<string, string> registersKeyValue = new Dictionary<string, string>();

string content = registersKeyValue
  .Where(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Key == "0x0003")
  .FirstOrDefault()
  .Value;
```